# XSL Getting node text without getting child nodes

Tags: xml, node.js, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<description>Valid Status Code required (“A”, “R”, “P”, “AR”)
    <br />
    <list type="bullet">
        <item>
            <description>A = Approved</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <description>R = Rejected</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <description>P = Partial</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <description>AR = Archived</description>
        </item>
    </list>
</description>
```

I'm trying to get simply: `Valid Status Code required (“A”, “R”, “P”, “AR”)` from the *description* XML node, not the child nodes.

```
<xsl:value-of select="description" />
```

Doing this returns the text from everything.

How can I ignore the child nodes?

```
<xsl:value-of select="description(ignore children)" /> // <- pseudo-code
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="description/text()"/>
```

Or, perhaps preferably:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(description/text())"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that ANYTHING in a XML DOM is a node, not only the element nodes. The string is in a text node. The location path for child nodes of description that are text nodes is:

`description/text()`

Any element node would be:

`description/*`

And any node:

`description/node()`